# What is the exponent in the definition of a Galois field called?

Tags: finite-fields

[From what I understand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field), when speaking of a Galois field $\operatorname{GF}(p^k)$, $p$ is called the *characteristic* of the field, and $p^k$ is the *order*. Does $k$ have a name by itself?

Comment: None, as far as I know, except it's the degree $[\mathbf{GF}(p^k):\mathbf{GF}(p)]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the degree of the extension, that is, $GF(p^k)$ as an extension of $GF(p)$ of degree $k$.